# ASP.Net GridView numeric paging with unlimited page numbers

Tags: asp.net, pagination

I have a GridView with Paging enabled and PageSettings Mode set to "Numeric". This setup currently displays correctly for ten pages or less:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

When it gets to eleven or more pages, it appends "..." (ellipsis) at the end to essentailly paginate the pages. Eleven or more pages looks like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

How can I configure this to a different number of pages? I want them to go up to 25 before showing the "...". Something like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 ...
```

**EDIT**

The answer is in the comments. Use the `PagerSettings-PageButtonCount` property, which would look something like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AllowPaging=true PageSize=5 PagerSettings-PageButtonCount=20></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: use PageSize property of GridView .

Comment: no he is not looking for that, he want to visibilty the number of pages ..

Comment: Oh Ok. Try this <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AllowPaging=true PageSize=5 PagerSettings-PageButtonCount=20></asp:GridView>

Comment: @ varadarajan; you can put this in answer.

Comment: Thanks @varadarajan, this was just the property I needed.

Answer (score 4):

use `PagerSettings-PageButtonCount` property of Gridview.

for example

```
<asp:GridView ID="[gridname]" runat="server" AllowPaging=true PageSize=[page size] PagerSettings-PageButtonCount=[number of page buttons]></asp:GridView>
```